# Plugin Using Grails

Tags: css, grails, upload, asset-pipeline, grails-2.4

I am using the uploadr plugin for grails 2.4.

Following the documentation I did the following

BuildConfig.groovy

```
 compile "org.grails.plugins:uploadr:1.2.11"
```

Then in my gsp

```
  <asset:javascript src="uploadr.manifest.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet href="uploadr.manifest.css"/>
```

Yet it does not display in my gsp.

After some research I realized that my asset piplein folder had only the default application.js and application.css. It did not contain the plugins js or stylesheets?

Is there some way of pointing them towards the assets folder of the plugin?

I then created my own folder in assets called flipcountdown->global_>uploadr and pasted all the files in there but the follwoing still doesnt work.

```
 <asset:javascript src="global/uploadr/uploadr.manifest.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet href="global/uploadr/uploadr.manifest.css"/>
```

What do I need to do to get this plugin working?

*** This is what I am using for the uplaodr

```
<uploadr:add name="myUploadrName" path="/my/upload/path" direction="up" maxVisible="8" unsupported="/my/controller/action" rating="true" voting="true" colorPicker="true" maxSize="204800" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugins assets should be pulled in automatically. You don't need to copy them to the project `assets`. The asset tags resolve to urls such as,

```
http://localhost:8080/uploadr/assets/uploadr.manifest.css?compile=false
http://localhost:8080/uploadr/assets/uploadr.manifest.js?compile=false
```

See if you can access the above urls directly.

Furthermore, check your browser dev console and see the network tab for any 404s for any resources. That may give you a clue to any problems with the assets.